# Making sure a MySQL field timestamp is not older than 1 hour of current time

Tags: mysql, timestamp

OK so I have looked at lots of similar questions on here but none seem to work. If I am short-sighted or lack the ability to search properly I apologise in advance.

So what I need to do is check if a `TIMESTAMP`in my MySQL database i.e. 15:55:13 is no older than 1 exact hour of the current time when a script is run.

If I have missed any needed code please let me know.

What I have thus far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT * 
                               FROM web_users
                               WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
                               AND last_pass_reset < last_pass_reset
                               INTERVAL 1 HOUR")
                               or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

What I have tried prior:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
                               FROM web_users
                               WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
                               AND last_pass_reset < NOW()-INTERVAL 1 HOUR")
                               or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Also:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT *
                               FROM web_users
                               WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
                               AND last_pass_reset < DATE_SUB(CURTIME(),
                               INTERVAL 1 HOUR)")
                               or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

So my understanding is that I would require the match to make sure any manipulated SQL time is not less than the **last_pass_reset** nor greater than 1 hour.

Thanks.

EDIT::

this is the updated sql query to make sure i have inputted correctly.

```
        // Perform a database search using the paramteres of the global variable
        $result = mysqli_query($link, "SET @scriptStartTime = CONCAT(CUR_DATE(), ' ', CUR_TIME())
                                       SELECT *
                                       FROM web_users
                                       WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
                                       AND last_pass_reset > DATE_SUB(@scriptStartTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)")

                                       or die(mysqli_error($link));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`NOW()` returns a `timestamp`, `CUR_TIME()` just the `time`.

> if a TIMESTAMP is no older than 1 exact hour of the current time

translates to me to:

> now is 12:34:56, so I want all records which have last_pass_reset between 11:34:56 and 12:34:56

right? Then this should work:

```
SET @scriptStartTime = NOW();

SELECT *
FROM web_users
WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
AND last_pass_reset > DATE_SUB(@scriptStartTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Another cheesy way:

```
SELECT *
FROM web_users, (SELECT @scriptStartTime:=NOW()) v
WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
AND last_pass_reset > DATE_SUB(@scriptStartTime, INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
```

Final solution:

```
SELECT *
FROM web_users
WHERE pass_reset_token='".$token."'
AND last_pass_reset > TIME(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 HOUR))
```

Comment: I have tried that variant also, sorry I did not mention it. If the database timestamp field holds '15:55:33' and the current time was 16:07:33 `DATE_SUB` would return a value of `15:07:33` which makes `last_pass_reset` greater than and false.

Comment: All I can think is that the result of `DATE_ADD` would have to be +1 hour of `last_pass_reset` and then if `now()` was between `last_pass_reset` and `DATE_ADD` then it would be true?

Comment: See updated answer. Gotta go now, but will be glad to help further if needed tomorrow.

Comment: Thank you for the update, I have not used the SET command like you have posted before. I copied that into the same `SQL` query but it returned a syntax error. does the `SET` go into the same query string?

Comment: @DanielWrigley Yes, it does. The `@scriptStartTime` variable will be valid only for your connection and will be thrown away when you close it. What is the syntax error exactly?

Comment: Also, the `SET` command is not necessary. But since you wanted to use the time of script start in your query... The value of NOW() stays the same in the query as long as it runs. But if you have multiple queries in your script...you get the point

Comment: Hi tombom, sorry for delay I have been in meetings. I have added your code as I have in-putted to the bottom of the original question, could you please look and check for errors? as the only error i get is one stating there is a syntax error in the query on the `SELECT` line.

Comment: @DanielWrigley You are missing a `;` before the select command to finish the previous command. Though I'm not sure if you can post 2 statements in one `mysqli_query()`

Comment: If you don't have multiple statements in your script, just remove the `SET ...` and replace `@scriptStartTime` with `NOW()` in the query.

Comment: @DanielWrigley I added another possibility in my answer to avoid the "2 statements in one mysqli_query()" problem.

Comment: Thank you for the assistance so far, I have just tried you updated code; the cheesyway, as I dont understand the other one sadly. I just tested it and sadly the SQL query still doesnt collect the correct time which matches with the database field and checks if it is older than 1 hour.

Comment: the time i have in the database is `13:16:21` so the SQL query needs to make sure that the current time is either equal to and not larger than 14:16:21 and then collect the correct row.

Comment: I have realised that I don't want to be using `NOW()` AS that returns the date as well as the time, `CURTIME()` would call back the correct format to match against `13:16:21`

Comment: Yes, just wanted to ask of what datatype last_pass_reset is.

Comment: last_pass_reset is using a `time` datatype

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/21461/discussion-between-tombom-and-daniel-wrigley)